# How do I export a single function as a module in Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a module called `foo` that has many internal functions, but ultimately boils down to a single external function `foo()`. When using this module/function, I'd like to do

```
import foo
foo(whatever)
```

instead of

```
from foo import foo
foo(whatever)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You *could* monkey patch the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dictionary to make the name of your module point to the function instead of your module.

`foo.py` (the file defining your module `foo`) would look like this

```
import sys

def foo(x):
    return x + x

sys.modules[__name__] = foo
```

then you can use this module from a different file like this

```
import foo
print(foo(3))
6
```

There are probably reasons for why you **shouldn't do this**. `sys.modules` isn't supposed to point to functions, when you do `from some_module import some_function`, the module `some_module` is what gets added to `sys.modules`, not the function `some_function`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not strictly possible. Python module names are ment to help the programmer distinguish between modules. So even if you had one function, `bar` in your module `foo`, using `import foo` will still need a `foo.bar()`. You're probably better off just using `from foo import *`.

However there may be a way around this. Python also has built-in functions, and you may be able to add your own functions to this. Doing so might require rewriting the compile though.

So conclusion: writing `from foo import *` isn't all that ugly and is a lot easier and prettier than the long way around.

Comment: Unless you're just quickly trying something out in the REPL, never do `import *`. You can do `from foo import bar, baz, whatever`.